# Black screen trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 but not other Linux distros

Tags: boot, 16.04

I have a HP laptop and I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 using a USB pen drive, but after I choose to boot using the usb, the screen goes dark and nothing happens.
If I choose UFI mode, I can get to the dark menu with options to try ubuntu or install, but no matter what I choose, the screen goes dark.
If I DON'T choose UFI mode, it shows the purple-ish ubuntu color for a second and then goes black without showing any options like in UFI.

Note: the laptop has no screen, I'm using an external monitor with it, also it works fine installing other OS (currently Manjaro installed and windows before it) but It worked before with ubuntu, I don't know what could be doing this now.

specs: AMD Fusion™ APU A8-4500M Quad Core; AMD Radeon™ HD 7670M.

Thank you

Comment: I don't have AMD Radeon GPU but I've certainly noticed many Q&A in AskUbuntu regarding your platform. Have you searched the many questions on that topic?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I have seen a lot of them, but none helped me so far. That's why I have decided to finally ask myself.